# Docker containers not registering ips

Tags: docker, jupyter

I'm trying to run Docker Jupyter books on my computer.  The command docker run -p 8888:8888 dir/jupyter-notebook creates the container, but fails to link the container to a local ip.  Trying to run the minimal notebook example from the docker site does work, and I can view that. What could be breaking my local docker images?  Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: How do you know it fails to link the container to a local IP? What happens if you start the conainer and open "localhost:8888"? Is any error message shown?